# What is the effect from 'change of delivery type' upgrade?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I don't know if that's the right name of the upgrade, please correct it if i'm wrong.

How does the change of cargo (like car parts to hazardous chemicals), the one on upgrades, affects your game/delivery?

I really don't get the direct effect of that upgrade though since it's not explained thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

It adds possibility to take this kind of cargo.
On the right side of the transport details mission there is an arrow that specify what kind of cargo you will be given.